# Chart.js Time series - x axis that change depending on timestamp

Tags: javascript, time-series, chart.js, intervals, postgresql-10

I have a question. I'm using Chart.js on a project and I need to create a history graph. I get data from a database (PostgreSQL 10). I have heartbeat values as integer of patients and timestamp (when it was registered). But I need to make a time series graph with intervals depending on the total time. I mean:

- There's a patient with heartbeat values registered on total of 2 months and the graph needs to fill x axis with intervals of 1 week. But depends on total of time of heartbeats on database. Or there's a total of 1 day and it fills with intervals of 2 hours.

**Is it possible to Chart.js get those data (heartbeat and timestamp) and auto interval timestamp depending on total time? I mean I don't want to invent the wheel.**

```
heartbeat   patient_id    timestamp_register
58          2             2019-01-10 04:47:09.885053
50          2             2019-01-11 10:52:37.904854
85          2             2019-01-12 23:26:50.961469
118         2             2018-01-13 17:09:10.064487
84          2             2019-01-14 07:26:32.85583
27          2             2019-01-15 07:26:32.85583
.           .             .
.           .             .
.           .             .
30          2             2020-01-10 09:26:32.85583
```

In this case it would need to fill x axis with intervals of 2 months, for example.

**Something like this but with auto interval depending on timestamp:**
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/financial.html

Comment: Please could you share some code that you have tried already with?

Comment: Could you please share your payload from database

Comment: @T.Short I only tried to build a stored procedure on database that gets data on intervals but I don't want to build something from zero that already exists. That's why I'm looking for some solution on Chart.js

Comment: I edited it with more details. @Mojo Is that what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example you can use as a start. You will have to play with the time properties like `unit`, `minUnit`, `displayFormats`, `min`, `max` and so on...

I'm not a big fan of the way `chart.js` chooses to distribute and display the ticks.

Note: this example here does not feature a way to choose the amount of displayed data. It just displays all data you give it.

https://jsbin.com/fiyopogapa/1/edit?js,output

```
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        minUnit: 'hour',
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'MMM D',
          week: 'MMM YYYY',
          month: 'MMM YYYY',
          quarter:  'MMM YYYY'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```